The 'calls' attribute is invalid - The value '' is not within allowed values range
I want to add a condition that allowed me to add custom rate limit only if it is given(local.limit == true) otherwise dont add it in policy. it works fine whe there is rate limit provided but if there is no rate limit then it gives error

The 'calls' attribute is invalid - The value '' is not within allowed
values range.

as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/rate-limit-policy calls is required field.
variable "rate_limit" {
  type = string
}

locals {
  j       = "context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault(\"Authorization\", \"\").AsJwt()?.Subject"
  s       = "context.Subscription.Id"
  limit   = var.rate_limit != ""
}
<choose>
          <when condition="@((${local.j} != null || ${local.s} != null) && (${local.limit == true}))">
               <rate-limit-by-key calls="${var.rate_limit}" renewal-period="60" counter-key="@(${local.j} ?? ${local.s})" />
          </when>
          <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("ApiKey") == "Default")">
               <rate-limit-by-key calls="100" renewal-period="60" counter-key="@(context.Request.IpAddress)" />
          </when>
</choose>

The plan lookslike this
<when condition="@((context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization", "").AsJwt()?.Subject != null || context.Subscription.Id != null) && (false))">
   <rate-limit-by-key calls="" renewal-period="60" counter-key="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization", "").AsJwt()?.Subject ?? context.Subscription.Id)" />
</when>


If you are passing the first condition, it is throwing an error? @Panda

Yes, If I get rate limit from some API config It workes fine but if if there is not rate limit from some API config then it is throwing error. Is there any way to add condition dynamically like if rate-limit is pprovided then only condition should be added.

Instead of passing (${local.limit == true}), can you try giving only ${local.limit} so that it checks if it exists or not and continue with the condition statements. @Panda

I had tried it before but it gives samer error

Have you tried with  @Panda

Do you have any example?

<choose><when condition='@((${local.s} != null) && ${local.limit})'>   <empty-policy /> </when> Similar way. @Panda

but also I want to add policy when local.limit is false that means when rate limit is provided. And dont want to add policy when rate limit is not provided.

Add local.limit == false  and try adding the above one. @Panda

you mean two seperate conditions?<when condition="@((${local.j} != null || ${local.s} != null) && (${local.limit == true}))">                <rate-limit-by-key calls="${var.rate_limit}" renewal-period="60" counter-key="@(${local.j} ?? ${local.s})" />  <when condition='@((${local.s} != null) && ${local.limit})'>   <empty-policy />


Yes. Have you tried that? @Panda

i did not try because this is not what I wanted. I found another solution

I managed to fix it
locals {
  j         = "context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault(\"Authorization\", \"\").AsJwt()?.Subject"
  s   = "context.Subscription.Id"
  limit             = var.rate_limit != ""
  rate_limit_config = <<XML
  <when condition="@(${local.j} != null || ${local.s} != null)">
                <rate-limit-by-key calls="${var.rate_limit}" renewal-period="60" counter-key="@(${local.j} ?? ${local.s})" />
          </when>
  XML
}


<choose>
        ${var.api.rate_limit != "" ? local.rate_limit_config : var.api.rate_limit}
          <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("ApiKey") == "Default")">
      <rate-limit-by-key calls="10" renewal-period="1" counter-key="@(context.Request.IpAddress)" />
          </when>

